# How to calculate a date a week ago from today

Tags: perl

I wanna calculate the date a week ago from today with a specific format and put it in to a variable. For example, today is `Nov 21st. 2014`, and I wanna print out: Last week is `2014-11-14`.

I know we can use `Date::Calc` module, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) and [`Time::Seconds`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Seconds.html) core modules,

```
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $t = localtime() - ONE_WEEK;
print $t->ymd;
```

output

```
2014-11-14
```

Comment: `Time::Piece` has been a standard Perl module since 5.10.

Comment: It's good to use this module, but I've got another question: are we only able to use pre-defined time period like ONE_WEEK, ONE_DAY? How about TWO_DAYS? How could I make it work?

Comment: @NeilWang try `2* ONE_DAY`

Answer (score 3):

#### DateTime version

```
use DateTime;
my $now = DateTime->now(time_zone => 'local')->subtract(weeks => 1);
print $now->ymd, ' ',$now->hms;
```

#### Date::Calc version

Instead of one week you can subtract 7 days using Date::Calc module

```
use Date::Calc qw(Add_Delta_Days);
my @date = Add_Delta_Days( 2014, 11, 21, -7 );
print join('-', @date);

OUTPUT
    2014-11-14
```

Comment: Which operating system you are using?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5

Comment: You can install  perl-DateTime package with the package manager, probably?

Comment: I added the a solution with Date::Calc module too that might help. But instead of week you can try mentioning that in days.

Comment: DateTime is probably overkill for this. Time::Piece is core Perl.

Comment: Hmm looks nice. I never used that though. Does it take care of dst time shifts?

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple using [Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-6.47/lib/Date/Manip.pod)

```
    use Date::Manip;
    my $today = ParseDate("today");
    my $weeksago = DateCalc($today,"-7d");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just subtract X days from the "mday" field of localtime? This example shows subtracting 60 days from the end of august. I'm not sure who corrects the month but I think I'm getting the right answer...

```
$ date
Wed Aug 30 14:34:14 DFT 2017
$ perl -MPOSIX -e '@t=localtime time; $t[3] -= 60; print strftime( "%Y/%m/%d", @t), "\n";'
2017/07/01
```